# Pattern match on type in Clojure spec conformer

Tags: clojure

I am using Clojure spec to conform (coerce) a 1 or 2 value of a number type or string into a 1, 2 or `:clojure.spec/invalid`.

```
(require [[clojure.spec :as s]
          [clojure.core.match :as m]])

(defn parse-number [n]
  "Parses a string or number in a safe way."
  (m/match [n]
    [_ :guard number?] n
    [_] (Integer/parseInt (re-find #"\A\d+" n))))

(defn one-or-two? [n]
  (try
    (let [parsed-n (parse-number n)]
      (m/match [parsed-n]
        [1] 1
        [2] 2
        [_] :clojure.spec/invalid))
    (catch Exception _
      :clojure.spec/invalid)))

(s/def ::one-or-two (s/conformer one-or-two?))
```

Now we can conform and validate values like this:

```
(s/valid? ::one-or-two 1))   ; => true
(s/valid? ::one-or-two 2)    ; => true
(s/valid? ::one-or-two 3)    ; => false
(s/conform ::one-or-two "1") ; => 1
(s/conform ::one-or-two "2") ; => 2
(s/conform ::one-or-two :2)   ; => :clojure.spec/invalid
```

I have a feeling that the `parse-number` and `one-or-two` method can be combined into one, but I do not see how. Can it be done, and if so how?

Comment: Is this a simplication of a more complex problem? Or is it really just letting 1, 2, "1", "2" being valid? Because then, I'd say you don't have to parse this. You could just match against those 4 options + invalid. Apart from that I don't see a reason for the use of the regex. If a non-digit string arrives, the re-find returns nil. Which will when passed to `parseInt` produce an exception equally when passing a wrong string to it directly.

Comment: @AntonHarald Yes this problem is not more complex than this. Thanks.